# Category filter returning all entries

Tags: categories, relations, filter, category

I've been trying to build a category filter. I managed to make my buttons respond with categories but the returned entries on the page stay the same. So when I click one of the links "/?category=koop" gets added to the URL, but my entries don't respond upon that URL. I do have added the categories in the CP and assigned them to my entries.

Here is the code of my filters:

```
{% if craft.request.getParam('offerCategory') is not null %}

    {% set offerCategory = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getParam('offerCategory')) %}
    {% set offers = craft.entries.section('offers').relatedTo(offerCategory).find() %}

{% else %}

    {% set offers = craft.entries.section('offers').find() %}

{% endif %}
```

And my button list

```
{% for offerCategory in craft.categories.group('offerTypes').find() %}
    <li>
        <a class="mart-button" href="{{craft.request.url}}/?category={{ offerCategory.slug }}">{{ offerCategory.title }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm quite new to Craft. One of the resources I'm using to build this is: http://craftcookbook.net/recipes/197.

If anyone knows what I'm overseeing, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest changing the couple places where you use getParam('offerCategory') to getParam('category') so it matches the parameter set in the URL.